# Delayed results when publishing AMQP messages

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I am trying to develop a protocol translator: this means there is a *sender.py* (speaks MQTT ZMQ or another protocol), *translator.py* (speaks both sender's and receiver's protocols) and *receiver.py* (speaks AMQP). The sender sends messages in a protocol that could be MQTT, ZMQ... The translator takes those messages, reads the payload and publishes it to the RabbitMQ broker. Then the receiver.py gets the messages by subscribing to a queue that was previously binded to an exchange using a binding key (say: '#/data').

Now the problem is each time a MQTT message is received I make a AQMP publish. Nevertheless, the AMQP receiver doesn't get all the messages published. Only when a 4th message or so is published then the first of all messages is received. Then if I publish another 4 I can see the seconth message published the first time is received in the AMQP subscriber.

The code of the translator is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pika
import json
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    #When connected to MQTT broker
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    #Subscribe to all topics in MQTT
    client.subscribe("#")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
   #When mqtt message is received
    message=json.loads(msg.payload)
    allData=message['data']

    for eachData in allData:
        message['data']=eachData
        routKey='eachData['topic']/data'
        publish_amqp(routKey,message)

def publish_amqp(rk,msg):
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='translator', routing_key=rk, body=json.dumps(msg))
    print(rk+' - - '+json.dumps(msg))


client = mqtt.Client('MQTT_to_AMQP_Translator')
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect('localhost', 1883, 60)


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='translator',type='topic')

client.loop_forever()
```

However if I use **this second code** to publish instead of the only sentece (basic_publish) placed in the method of the first block of code I get normal results. The code is:

```
def publish_amqp(rk, msg):
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.exchange_declare(exchange='translator',type='topic')
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='translator', routing_key=rk, body=json.dumps(msg))
    print(rk+' - - '+json.dumps(msg))
    connection.close()
```

Then everything works just fine with this last approach. I don't really like this approach since this last code means having to stablish a connection, declare some values, publish and disconnect and using the first code I can 'just publish' without needing to reconnect and so on.

Why is the first code delaying the messages to the receiver? I have been dealing with this problem since a couple of days and only the second block of code (where I connect, publish and disconnect for each message) works OK.

Comment: I would recommend that you try the pika authors new library instead. Pika is buggy, and not thread safe at all. https://github.com/gmr/rabbitpy You could also try my thread safe amqp library https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm

Comment: Another thing you could try is to enable confirm_delivery to ensure that the messages are getting delivered properly.
http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/blocking_delivery_confirmations.html